# Cakephp-Change default URL

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I use cakephp 2.0
My default URL website:

> abc.com

I want: when i type url "abc.com", the browser 'll redirect automatically to

> abc.com/eng
>    Thanks your help!

Comment: So why don't you do it?

Comment: Sorry! my question is not clarity. i edited my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add or edit of **app/Config/routes.php** file

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'YourController', 'action' => 'YourAction'));
```

Thanks